# Использование свойств для list описанных в классе

Tags: c++, ооп, list, список

Вечер добрый, проблема заключается в не знании как сделать так, чтобы `list` использовал "инструкции" *(не знаю как правильно назвать)* которые описаны в классе BD, как написать чтобы работало? В данном коде пишет ошибку что не хватает точки с запятой, но я их расставлял везде где можно всё равно одно и тоже.

В документации к `list` ничего не нашёл подобного, хотя может и прошляпил.

Если интересно, суть задания создать мини-базу данных, с поиском по ней и сортировками разными. (именно сама БД в коде должна быть, **не обязательно с помощью list а вообще**)

Написал этот код ориентируясь на другой код из C# поэтому написал именно так `list<BD>`, как правильно не знаю.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class BD
{
public:
   int number_reis;
   string data_otpravki;
   float stoimost;
};

int main ()
{

}

void baza()
{
   list<BD> numbers;
   numbers.assign{number_reis=5, data_otpravki = "asdasd", stoimost = 12.50
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не понял вопроса. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: `numbers.push_back({5, "asdasd", 12.50});`? Или вам именно с названиями полей хочется?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А так можно тоже? Напишите как интересно просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис для добавления объекта тривиального класса может выглядеть следующим образом

```
numbers.push_back( { 5, "asdasd", 12.50f } );
```

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

class BD
{
public:
   int number_reis;
   std::string data_otpravki;
   float stoimost;
};

void baza()
{
    std::list<BD> numbers;
    numbers.push_back( { 5, "asdasd", 12.50f } );
}

int main() 
{
    baza();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ааа вот оно как, спасибо огромное.